# Asp.net C# Webform forms Generator/Builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm looking for a simple Asp.net C#  Webform forms Generator/Builder

Something Very simular to http://wufoo.com/form-builder/ (more basic would also be ok)  but in a .Net Implemetion and local as opposed to a paid cloud servcie.

Anyone know where i can find this ?

This is for intergration into an existing C# Webform Application to allow staff(non developers) to easily create and store forms that they are able to then present to public users of the system.

Ps I have already looked at http://frevvo.com but thier prices are *retarded*.

Other Questions of a similar nature end up with a bunch of ASP.Net MVC answers.
Just to make it clear, I'm looking for a WebForm solution as it is built on WebForms.

Comment: Are you trying to give the client a product, or are you trying to simplify your own work?  Meaning that someone in accounting will come along, fill in some textboxes and check a few checkboxes and get a new form, or they make a request for a form to you and you have to go build (or generate) and deploy it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm looking for a C# based form generator system as well, and came up with the following solution:

1. Use the  [jquery-form-builder-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-builder-plugin/) to give a user-friendly UI to the users. This posts a JSON object to the server
2. Use ASP.Net to save the JSON and render the form to the user

Handling the JSON is made easy creating an ASMX using `System.Web.Extensions` in .Net 3.5. A good series for reference with doing this is [here](http://encosia.com/category/asmx-mistakes-and-misconceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

I am all for maintaining compatibility with an existing application, but this is the web so you just have to link off somewhere...

Your question appears to define the stated goals of the Microsoft [LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) project.

> LightSwitch is a simplified self-service development tool that enables you to build business applications quickly and easily for the desktop and cloud

just replace `cloud` with `web based forms`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: telling a client to get LightSwtich, train their non technical staff and to do it themselves isn't really realistic.

Comment: @RY4N If this for someone external to your company then I agree.  If for an external client then I'd guess that they are either expecting you to build the forms or the framework yourself.

Comment: its a modular web app, this would simply be a way that they could communicate directly to obtain information from their customers, it's desired that they can do this themselves via a form building tool embedded into one of the current modules.

Comment: Would you be interested in any pointers on building such a framework yourself?

Comment: This search isn't going well so i probably will end up coding it. so any help would be cool